# Nav button element stretching across page

Tags: html, css, button, display, navigationbar

Pretty new designer, have a problem with my navbar button.  It's currently only 100PX wide, and is fixed in place, so it allows the rest of the page to scroll by it.  But it is still page-wide, so when other links are parallel to it, they don't work, I assume because they are under the div.
here's my html:

```
<div class="sideNavButton" onclick="openNav()"
         width="100px" >
        <span>
        <small class="form-text text-muted">links
        </small>
        <img th:src="@{../../images/RunshareLogo.jpg}"
             width="100px"
             style="border-style:outset; border-color:silver;"
        height="100px" />
        </span>
    </div>
```

and here's my CSS:

```
.sideNavButton {
    top:0px;
    display:inline;
}
```

the button works great, but I'd like it to only perform when inside the square.  When I have display:inline, it only works while in the square, but it still blocks across the screen, and if I do display:block, it activates the side nav bar if you click anywhere parallel to the button.
[image]

This is an image of what I'm talking about.  The "RunShare" square is a navbutton, and the little arrows in the table header change the view to various sorted views.  They all work fine, but when the table header is parallel to the navbutton, the cursor doesn't change to the finger icon, and you can't click on the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your  width in CSS.

> HTML

```
<div class="sideNavButton" onclick="openNav()">
    <span>
    <small class="form-text text-muted">links
    </small>
    <img th:src="@{../../images/RunshareLogo.jpg}"
         width="100px"
         style="border-style:outset; border-color:silver;"
    height="100px" />
    </span>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.sideNavButton {
top:0px;
display:inline;
width: 100px; /*or 10vw(if your prefer viewport width)*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried this, but it still seems to block access to other links while they are parallel to the clickable element.  I've tried making it a button, and a span, to see if that would limit it's width, but it still seems to stretch across the screen, even though it's transparent past the 100 px limit of the image I'm using as a button.

Answer (score 0):

Found that that when I added "float:left" it stopped blocking across the screen:

```
.sideNavButton {
    top:0px;
    display:inline;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```